# Нужна помощь с программой аутентификации с++

Tags: c++, файлы, аутентификация

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    char login[16];
    char buffLOGIN[16];
    char password[32];
    char buffPASS[32];
    int attempt;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    std::ifstream auth("auth.txt");
    auth.getline(buffLOGIN, 16);
    auth.getline(buffPASS, 32);

    std::cout << "Добро пожаловать! \nДля входа в систему необходимо ввести идентификатор пользователя и пароль. \n";
    for (attempt = 1; attempt <= 3; attempt++)
    {
            std::cout << "Введите идентификатор пользователя: ";
            std::cin >> login;
            std::cout << "Введите пароль пользователя: ";
            std::cin >> password;
            if (buffLOGIN != login || buffPASS != password)
            {
                std::cout << "Идентификатор или пароль пользователя введены не верно.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            else if (buffLOGIN == login && buffPASS == password)
            {
                std::cout << "Поздравляем, Вы успешно вошли в систему!";
            }
    }
    if (attempt > 3) {
        std::cout << "Возможность осуществлять попытки входа исчерпана. \n"
                  << "Для выхода из программы нажмите любую клавишу.";
    }

    auth.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Написал такую программку аутентификации, но не работает вариант, когда всё ПРАВИЛЬНО.
Может кто подскажет, где мог ошибиться?

Answer (score 1):

Сравнения типа

```
buffLOGIN == login
```

всегда ложны, потому что вы сравниваете не содержимое строк (они у вас не `sting`, а C-style), а два указателя. Понятно, что они разные...

Используйте функцию [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).